# GetListItems in Visual Studio Workflow for SharePoint 2013

Tags: list, workflow, sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2013

I know there is a LookupListItem activity in Visual Studio Workflow for SharePoint 2013. Is there a GetListItems activity, which will return multiple list items based on a filter condition similar to GetListItems method in OM?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, SharePoint doesn't have such functionality. I would suggest trying to use 3rd party product [Plumsail Workflow Actions Pack](https://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/) it has [Get Items by Query](https://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/docs/documents-list-items-processing/#GetItems) workflow action which allows you to this.

I'm one of the developers of the product and I'm proud of this.

PS: Alternatively you always can make REST query to select an items.